# adding percentile from (dates) multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, percentile

Wanted to ask where I can add 1 column to see the percentile (30%) from dates columns here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpvVj.png)

so after 2022-03-03 I want to add percentile

Comment: Can you provide a simple input and its expected output to your question? Hopefully as text to make it easier to read.

Comment: df[[put your list of dates here]].quantile(.3, axis=1)

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['one', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'two',
                           'two'],
                   'bar': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'baz': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'dates': ['2022-02-01','2022-02-02','2022-02-03','2022-02-01','2022-02-02','2022-02-03'],
                   'zoo': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'q', 'w', 't']})

table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='baz', index=['foo', 'bar'],
                    columns=['dates'], aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index().fillna(0)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the starting point is *table* generated as you described
in your comment.

The trick to get your quantile is the following sequence of conversions:

- `table.columns.to_series()` - take columns from *table* as a *Series*.
- `iloc[2:]` - strip first 2 column names (only *foo* and *bar*, since
  *dates* is the name of this *Series*).
  So far the column names are of *string* type.
- `pd.to_datetime(…)` - convert them to *datetime*.
- `astype('int64')` - convert them to numbers.
- `quantile(.3)` - compute your quantile, so far as a number, since this is the only way you can compute quantiles.
- `pd.to_datetime(…)` - convert back to *datetime*.

So the whole code is:

```
result = pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime(table.columns.to_series().iloc[2:])
    .astype('int64').quantile(.3))
```

and the result for your source data is:

```
Timestamp('2022-02-01 14:24:00')
```

I'm not sure how/where you want to insert this value into your *table*.
So far we have a value of *Timestamp* type. Do you want it to be the
name of a column to be added? If yes then you should specify also the
content of this new column.

But at least you have now the quantile computed.
Make any use of it as you wish.

Comment: hi bro thanks for repliying but, I expect the answer is percentile from range 2022-02-01 until 2022-02-03

Comment: The result (*2022-02-01 14:24:00*) is in the range you specified. If you want only a date, without time part, normalize it.